# PDO подключение в классе

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, pdo

Добрый день, сделал запрос, отрабатывает нормально , но PHPstorm подчеркивает что функция db_connection 'Missing return statement'

```
class DB
{
    protected $connection_db_link;
    public $db_users = 'root';
    public $db_host = 'localhost';
    public $db_name = 'gallery_images';
    public $db_pass = 'root';

    function db_connection(){
        try{
            $this->connection_db_link = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;$this->db_name",$this->db_users,$this->db_pass);
            $this->connection_db_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            return $this->connection_db_link;
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
//    function display_connection(){
//        if($this->connetction_db_link == true){
//            echo 'connection success';
//        }
//    }
}
```

Вопрос: Как сделать правильно???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

правильно сделать вот так

```
function db_connection(){
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;$this->db_name",$this->db_users,$this->db_pass);
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $this->conn;
}
```

Ловить исключение только для того чтобы вывести его на экран - это головотяпство граничащее с вредительством.

Answer (score 2):

В случае исключения ничего не возвращается.
Добавь `return Null;` в блок `catch` или непосредственно перед окончанием функции.